# ELKI KNNDistancesSampler

Tags: knn, elki

Does anybody know what does the KNNDistancesSampler calculate in ELKI? I can see the java code for the function : https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/master/elki/src/main/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/KNNDistancesSampler.java, but I am really bad at java - I can see it should get the distance of its neighbors by getKNNDistance()...
Is it returning average distance(Euclidean by default) of the k-nearest neighbors of each point? I know it should be used for epsilon estimation of dbscan etc.etc., but I'd also like to know what it is doing...
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References for this are given in the class documentation:

> Martin Ester, Hans-Peter Kriegel, Jörg Sander, Xiaowei Xu
> A Density-Based Algorithm for Discovering Clusters in Large Spatial Databases
> with Noise
> Proc. 2nd Int. Conf. on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining (KDD '96)
>
> Erich Schubert, Jörg Sander, Martin Ester, Hans-Peter Kriegel, Xiaowei Xu
> DBSCAN Revisited, Revisited: Why and How You Should (Still) Use DBSCAN
> ACM Trans. Database Systems (TODS)

The class is returning a sample, not just the average, of the kNN distances to help choosing the epsilon parameter using the "elbow" method on that plot. It does not automate choosing this - it only produces the plot.

Comment: thank you for response, I read the explanation on the ELKI page and also in the other post.. I had problems understanding what is on y-axis - I guess I got confused by the name (sampler/sampling) and late working hours :) - I get it now, that is the distance to K-th neighbor of each point :) .... thank you for your time and sorry :)